How can I replace null values in polars with a prefix with ascending numbers?
I am trying to replace null values in my dataframe column by a prefix and ascending numbers(to make each unique).ie
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ name         ┆ asset_number │
│ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str          ┆ str          │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Office Chair ┆ null         │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 001    │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 005    │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         │
│ Table        ┆ null         │
│ Table        ┆ CMP - 007    │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘
""")

the null values should be replaced to something like PREFIX - 001,PREFIX - 002,...

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("asset_number").fill_null(
        "PREFIX - " + pl.int_range(pl.len()).cast(pl.String)
    )
)


Here's one way using the the ordinal rank over asset_number. To add leading 0s, we use .str.pad_start.
df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        "asset_number",
        "PREFIX - "
        + pl.all()
        .rank("ordinal")
        .over("asset_number")
        .cast(pl.String)
        .str.pad_start(3, "0"),
    )
)

Output:
shape: (8, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ name         ┆ asset_number │
│ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str          ┆ str          │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 001 │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 002 │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 003 │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 001    │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 005    │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 004 │
│ Table        ┆ PREFIX - 005 │
│ Table        ┆ CMP - 007    │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘

Full code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "Office Chair",
            "Office Chair",
            "Office Chair",
            "Office Chair",
            "Office Chair",
            "Office Chair",
            "Table",
            "Table",
        ],
        "asset_number": [
            None,
            None,
            None,
            "CMP - 001",
            "CMP - 005",
            None,
            None,
            "CMP - 007",
        ],
    }
)

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        "asset_number",
        "PREFIX - "
        + pl.all()
        .rank("ordinal")
        .over("asset_number")
        .cast(pl.String)
        .str.pad_start(3, "0"),
    )
)

print(df)


Thanks, it also works, and good catch on padding the numbers. Just out of curiosity, is this approach of using ordinal rank more performant on large datasets?

It'll probably be slower than int_range in the other answer but this assigns the numbers in a different way: int_range will skip numbers where the value is not null, so it assigns 0, 1, 2, 5, 6 while mine assigns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

This is what I actually wanted.Again, thanks a bunch!

Essentially a combination of the existing answers, but:
.is_null().cum_sum() is also a way to generate the ascending numbers.
pl.format can help with building strings.
df.with_columns(
   pl.format(
      "PREFIX - {}",
      pl.col("asset_number").is_null().cum_sum()
        .cast(pl.String)
        .str.pad_start(3, "0")
   )
)

shape: (8, 3)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ name         ┆ asset_number ┆ literal      │
│ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str          ┆ str          ┆ str          │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Office Chair ┆ null         ┆ PREFIX - 001 │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         ┆ PREFIX - 002 │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         ┆ PREFIX - 003 │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 001    ┆ PREFIX - 003 │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 005    ┆ PREFIX - 003 │
│ Office Chair ┆ null         ┆ PREFIX - 004 │
│ Table        ┆ null         ┆ PREFIX - 005 │
│ Table        ┆ CMP - 007    ┆ PREFIX - 005 │
└──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘

Which can be given to .fill_null()
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("asset_number").fill_null(
      pl.format(
         "PREFIX - {}",
         pl.col("asset_number").is_null().cum_sum()
           .cast(pl.String)
           .str.pad_start(3, "0")
      )
   )
)

shape: (8, 2)
┌──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ name         ┆ asset_number │
│ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str          ┆ str          │
╞══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 001 │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 002 │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 003 │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 001    │
│ Office Chair ┆ CMP - 005    │
│ Office Chair ┆ PREFIX - 004 │
│ Table        ┆ PREFIX - 005 │
│ Table        ┆ CMP - 007    │
└──────────────┴──────────────┘

